# hover grayscale to color fade script making image margins disappear

Tags: jquery, hover, fade

I'm currently struggling to get a WebDesignersWall script to function properly on my website.  On all my thumbnails in my galleries they currently DO fade from gray to color on hover, but each thumbnail is SUPPOSED to have a 14px bottom margin, which is canceled out when I apply the gray-hover-script to them.  Also, in the "Web" section, where the thumbnails are slightly larger, the right-hand thumbnails get pushed over a couple hundred pixels and make the DIV layer scroll.  Can anyone help?  Here's my test page:
http://whiterabbitstudio.us/test/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if moving this margin-bottom from img to p section helps. You can do it by adding `class="thumbnail"` to your `p` sections and then to stylesheet:

```
.thumbnail {
margin-bottom:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `align="right"` from your right `<td>` in the web thumbs table - that should  fix the wideness issue. Also apply a rule `.img_wrapper { margin-bottom: 14px }` in your CSS to fix the missing margin

Comment: talking off the right alignment definitely worked, and I used witpok's suggestion below to fix the margins.  Thanks!!